# Showing $[0,\infty)^2$ is not a differentiable manifold

Tags: manifolds

I have to show that $[0,\infty)^2$ is not a differentiable manifold. The problem is $(0,0)$ (because there doesn't exist a diffeomorphism between $[0,\infty)^2$ and $R^2$) but I don't know how to show that.

$[0,\infty)^2$ = $[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)$ (the non-negative part of the axes in $R^2$)

And then I am searching for a homeomorphism between $[0,\infty)^2$ and $H^2 := \{x=(x_1,x_2) \in R : x_2 ≥ 0 \}$ that is a diffeomorphism restricted to $[0,\infty)^2 - \{(0,0)\}$.

Thanks muchly!

Comment: What is $[0, \infty)^2$?

Comment: I write it in the question.

Comment: Please add all details of your relevant knowledge of the question and attempets you've made. Thanks for using TeX, by the way!

Comment: Are you trying to show the closed quadrant is not a _manifold_, or that it's not a _manifold with boundary_ (which is a special type of non-manifold)?

Comment: I try to show that it is not a differentiable manifold.

Comment: Do you know a homeomorphism to $H^2$ (where $x_2 ≥ 0$)?

Comment: The (corrected) second part of your question implies that you *are* considering manifolds with boundary (such as your $H^2$). Are you sure you have stated the first part correctly?

Comment: I know what you mean but the task is so formulated.

Comment: Has somebody an idea for the second part?

Comment: The second part is easy using polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was a manifold, then you have a chart $f:U\subset [0,\infty]^2\rightarrow V\subset R^2$ which contains $(0,0)$. $U$ can be supposed of the form $[0,c)^2$. Thus $V$ is open and contractible since $f$ is an homeomorphism. But the fundamental group of  $V-f((0,0)$ is not trivial (the fundamental group of an open subset $W$  of the plan without a point $u$ is not trivial. To see this, consider $B(u,r)\subset W$. You cannot deform the circle of center $u$ and radius $r/2$ which is contained in $W-\{u\}$ to a point). consider and $U-(0,0)$ its fundamental group is trivial.

Comment: Stick with the contractible argument: it works for all dimensions (no connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible when removing a point).

Comment: But all charts from $R^2$ to $R$ and your f is to $R^2$?

Comment: It is to $R^2$ since it is a 2-differentiable manifold. Anyway, a differentiable map $f:U\subset [0,\infty]^2\rightarrow R$ where $U$ is open cannot be injective.

Comment: I think it can be injective because R ist equipotent to (0,1) and the non-negative part of the axes in $R^2$ looks like R (if you "crease" it)

Comment: Sorry, I get it. Your are right.